# It's easy to 3d model a room via binocular vision, can it be done with 2 microphones and a beeper?

Tags: waves, acoustics, refraction, simulations, vision

Many algorithms exist to construct a 3d model from two cameras, is it possible to 3d model of a room via a speaker that produces a beep, and two microphones with arbitrarily good hearing skill (ie can sample continuously not in discrete "snapshot"s per second)?

A) assuming all object's in the room are made of the exact same material
B) Is it doable to create the map even if there are multiple types of material in the room?

Comment: That is to say, how much data is lost that can't be bruteforced or derived back as a result of the multiple unknown interactions that it occured in?

Comment: It seems to me this is exactly what bats do. Also, I have read that in geology its about this way that ore lodes are maped. They drill a deep hole, blow some dinamite down there and measure the reflected waves with multiple seismographers.

Comment: With bat echolocation though, A) that may just be nearest blockage and nearest open path, not a full sense of lengths of sides of objects.
B) Bat's have experience, & with experience one does not need to only extrapolate as much information is extracted from the current surroundings, with GAN Neural Networks, we can make the  "zoom and enhance" feature that violates information laws, but we use the past to fill in the blanks of the present, but is this doable without experience? Is max recoverable information (either knowable or bruteforcable)  equal to information of dimensions of the room?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pnas.org/content/110/30/12186.abstract

That's a link to a paper that claims to be able to do that with a "few" microphones.  Of course, if the room is not convex, it has the potential to fall prey to the illumination problem.

With 2 microphones, you should be able to get an arbitrarily good map, but there will be no way of determining its orientation around the axis created by the line through both microphones other than through adding parameters accounting for gravity or differences in pickup sound due to the 3d orientation of the microphones.